# cakephp how to make this queries

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to cakephp and I have a question about how to do this.I have two tables campaign and users,I make a query about the campaign table and about the results of doing a search on users.

```
|---------|
| Camping |
|---------|
|   id    |
|---------|
|   name  |
|---------|

|----------|
|   User   |
|----------|
|   id     |
|----------|
|   name   |
|----------|
|Camping_id|
```

In PHP I do the following a query `"Select * from camping where id = 1;"` and with the results I make another query in the users table `"Select * from user where camping_id = result.camping"`

Comment: You could replace result.camping by 1. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to filter by `Camping_id` you can use  `where` method like this:

```
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$query = $users->find()
    ->where(['Camping_id =' $campingId]);
```

If you want to filter by associative data you can achieve it this way:

```
$campingName = '...';
$users = TableRegistry::get('Users');
$query = $users->find()
    ->matching('Campings', function ($q) use ($campingName) {
        return $q->where(['Campings.name' => $campingName]);
    });
```

Documentation:

- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data
- https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data-via-matching-and-joins

Comment: The problem my version of cakephp is 2

Comment: Then you could use either [sub-queries](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#sub-queries) or [prepared statements](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements)
Just like this:
`$db = $this->getDataSource();`
`$db->fetchAll(`
`'SELECT * FROM user WHERE camping_id = ?',`
`array($camping_id)`
`);`